# error: '_GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN' does not name a type

Tags: c++, exception, c++14, clion, libstdc++

I am trying to compile some c++ code that I wrote on another machine running CentOS. I am trying to compile in Ubuntu 16.04 and despite having same version of gcc (4.8) and clion (2018.3) the code won't compile properly. One of the error is:

```
error: '_GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN' does not name a type
  what() const _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT {
```

I searched up on the internet for this error or tried to figure out what _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN means but couldn't find anything. The code still compiles properly on CentOS machines. I am probably missing some dependency or something but can't figure it out.

```cpp
class TestException : public std::exception {
public:
    /*!
     * @brief Default constructor to create a new instance of @c TestException
     *
     * @param what      A description of what might have gone wrong in the test
     * @param file      The file name where the error occurred (i.e. @c __FILE__ )
     * @param function  The function name in which the error occurred (i.e. @c __FUNCTION__ )
     * @param line      The line number where the error occurred. (i.e. @c__LINE__ )
     */
    TestException(const std::string what, const std::string file, const std::string function, const int line) {
        std::stringstream s;
        s << "TestException in file \"" << file << "\" in function \"" << function << "\" at line " << line
                << ": " << what;
        _msg = s.str();

    }

    //! @brief Return the error message as a string for use in error messages or tracing
    virtual const char*
    what() const _GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT {
        return _msg.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string _msg;  //!< @brief The formatted message string.
};
```

Comment: Why are you using such non-standard (and frankly library internal) symbols like `_GLIBCXX_TXN_SAFE_DYN`? Who told you about them, or where did you read about them?

Comment: Actually someone else wrote it and It didn't give me any problems before so I didn't changed them. Frankly I didn't understand them and that is why I decided not to mess with them.

Comment: I checked the system in which it works and there the g++ is located in a different location. Output of g++ version says that it is "g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)". Which is same version as the one located at /usr/bin/g++. I will get an explanation from the developer who wrote that code in a day or two and will hopefully post an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Use C++ 7.4.0 compiler or newer. I had the same experience with a costumer using GNU 5.5.0.
Atleast this worked out for us.

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0